# How to specify the jar file in manifest?

Tags: ant, jar, manifest.mf

I have created a mail.jar file and mywar.war file. What I need to set into the manifest.mf use the mail.jar as a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class-Path: ../relative/path_to_/mail.jar

EDIT:
Note: The relative path should be with reference from the directory where your program is starting.

Comment: Your spelling error is pretty entertaining, but you might want to correct it. Or specify strawberry or raspberry.

Answer (score 4):

You don't use a MANIFEST.MF to put a jar in the classpath of a war file. You just put it into WEB-INF/lib in the war file.